# Why isn't Google Code Prettify working on css?

Tags: html, css, syntax-highlighting, pre, google-code-prettify

I'm using prettify.js for some blog posts. It's handling my html, python, and js fine, but missing the css.

My html is:

```
<pre>
<code class="prettyprint lang-css">`

    .my-boxclass {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        cursor: help;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted grey;
    }
</code>
</pre>
```

and I'm importing prettify. Here's a jsfiddle of exactly what I'm doing (and it's not syntax highlighting the jsfiddle correctly either)
https://jsfiddle.net/kfdqLjm1/2/

Comment: @Martin, thanks for that edit, I was having a nightmare of a time trying to format that as one block

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the CSS language handler.  Try adding `?lang=css` after `run_prettify.js`.

Comment: That worked! Just out of curiosity, do you know why this is? The prettify doc says that css is automatically included. Also, will this prevent other languages (python, for example) from being automatically recognized?

Comment: I think I just got the docs wrong.  Which docs did you see this in?

Comment: https://github.com/google/code-prettify in the readme, FAQ-> 'for which languages does it work?' css is included in the list

Comment: "File extensions supported by default include:" that is missing CSS. Kind of silly but maybe filesize considerations?